# Android Studio - Add, Edit and Delete records using SQLite

Tags: javascript, xml, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am an extreme beginner at **Android Studio** and using **JavaScript**, so still learning and trying to grasp new concepts of android studio as a whole.

I am trying to create a **database** where it **adds, edits and deletes records** that a user manually inputs.

When I get to my *friends.xml* page (*friends.java*) and fill out the fields to add a user and press "ADD" it comes up with my toast to notify the user the data has been added succesfully however when I click on "VIEW DATA" (which links to *view_data.xml* (*listdata.java*)) it **doesn't seem to show the entries**.

It would be great if the answer would be put as simply as possible as I am still a beginner! Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

**friends.java**

```
    package com.example.chris.mobileappsassignment;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class friends extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText firstnameinput, lastnameinput, ageinput, addressinput;
    Button addbutton, viewbutton;
    DatabaseHelper dbhlpr;
    Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_friends);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        firstnameinput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstnameinput);
        lastnameinput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lastnameinput);
        ageinput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ageinput);
        addressinput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addressinput);
        addbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addbutton);
        viewbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.viewbutton);




        dbhlpr = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        addbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                boolean addOK = true;
                int age_as_int = -1;

                String firstName = firstnameinput.getText().toString();
                String lastName = lastnameinput.getText().toString();
                String age = ageinput.getText().toString();
                String address = addressinput.getText().toString();

                if (firstName.length() < 1) {
                    toastMessage("You must enter something in this field!");
                    firstnameinput.requestFocus();
                    addOK = false;
                }
                if (lastName.length() < 1) {
                    toastMessage("You must enter something in this field!");
                    lastnameinput.requestFocus();
                    addOK = false;
                }
                if (age.length() < 1) {
                    toastMessage("You must enter something in this field!");
                    ageinput.requestFocus();
                    addOK = false;
                }
                if (address.length() < 1) {
                    toastMessage("You must enter something in this field!");
                    addressinput.requestFocus();
                    addOK = false;
                }
                try {
                    age_as_int = Integer.parseInt(age);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    toastMessage("You must enter a valid Number in this field!");
                    ageinput.requestFocus();
                    addOK = false;
                }

                if (addOK) {
                    dbhlpr.addData(firstName,lastName,"????",age_as_int,address);
                    toastMessage("Friend Added!");
                }

            }
        });





        viewbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context,listdata.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });









    } //END ON CREATE CLASS











    //TOAST MSSG

    private void toastMessage(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(this,message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }









    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_friends, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }





}
```

**listdata.java**

```
package com.example.chris.mobileappsassignment;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static com.example.chris.mobileappsassignment.R.layout.view_data;

public class listdata extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "listdata";

    DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;

    private ListView mListView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(view_data);
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);
        mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        populateListView();

    } //END ONCREATE

    private void populateListView() {
        Log.d(TAG, "populate ListView: Displaying Data in the ListView");

        //get data and append to list
        Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.getData();
        Log.d("CURSORCOUNT", "Number of rows in Cursor =");
        Integer.toString(data.getCount());
        ArrayList<String> listData = new ArrayList<>();
        while(data.moveToNext()){
            //GET VALUE FROM DB IN COL1
            //then add to ArrayList
            listData.add(data.getString(1));
            listData.add(data.getString(2));
            listData.add(data.getString(3));
            listData.add(data.getString(4));
            listData.add(data.getString(5)); // NUMBERS REFER TO COL'S. (coloumns)

        }
        //create LIST ADAPTER AND SET ADAPTER
        ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listData);
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        //set on onclick listener to list view
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                String name = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(); // will grab object and convert to string
                Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: You clicked on " + name);

                Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.getItemID(name); // get ID associated with that name

                int itemID = 1;                 // WHEN SEARCHING // RETURN SOMETHING THAT EXISTS
                while (data.moveToNext()){
                    itemID = data.getInt(0);  // if data is returned
                }
                if (itemID > -1) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: The ID is: " + itemID);
                    Intent editScreenIntent = new Intent(listdata.this, EditDataActivity.class ); // VID2, 2.49
                    editScreenIntent.putExtra("id", itemID);
                    editScreenIntent.putExtra("name", name);
                    startActivity(editScreenIntent);
                }
                else {
                    toastMessage("No ID is associated with that name");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * customizable toast
     */
    private void toastMessage(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
} //END CLASS
```

**ERROR in logcat** when pressing "ADD"

```
    --------- beginning of crash
09-12 02:40:00.329 26615-26615/com.example.chris.mobileappsassignment E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                        Process: com.example.chris.mobileappsassignment, PID: 26615
                                                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
                                                                                            at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:128)
                                                                                            at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:4449)
                                                                                            at com.example.chris.mobileappsassignment.friends$2.onClick(friends.java:99)
                                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: That's a lot of probably unnecessary code, please make sure you read this before you post any other questions to SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the column called **address** couldn't be found in the table named **friends_table** this is as per :-

```
09-10 20:38:48.892 10003-10003/com.example.chris.mobileappsassignment E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting address=Mike lastname=Mike firstname=Mike age=Mike malefemale=Mike
                                                                                            android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table friends_table has no column named address (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO friends_table(address,lastname,firstname,age,malefemale) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
```

It is likely that the definition used to create the table needs to be changed or that the definition has been changed but that it has been implemented because the database's `onCreate` method has not been run.

The `onCreate` method only runs automatically when the database itself is created, that being once for the lifetime of the database file. There are 3 easy ways to get `onCreate` to run, noting that **ALL 3 WILL DELETE ANY EXISTING DATA IN THE DATABASE**.

- Uninstall the App.
- Clear the App's Data.
- If the onUpgrade method drops the respective table or tables AND it calls `onCreate` then the verion number of the database can be incremented.

As such you need to

- a) Ensure that your table definition includes the **address** column (and also columns **lastname**, **firstname**, **age** and **malefemale**)
- b) get `onCreate` to run by 1 of the three methods above (*there are other ways around the issue for those who want need to retain the existing data*).

Again, from the log, it is likely you have an issue with how you prepare the data within the **`addData`** as you are trying to insert the same data into all columns e.g. `Error inserting address=Mike lastname=Mike firstname=Mike age=Mike malefemale=Mike` would result in lastname, firstname, age, malefemale all having the value **Mike** (*sheesh I didn't know I was that popular :)*)

Looking at your **friends** class you use (as one example):-

```
            if (firstnameinput.length() !=0) {
                AddData(firstName);
                firstnameinput.setText(""); .........
```

You are passing a single paremeter to the  `AddData` method, so it is likely that this one parameter is being used as the data to populate all of the columns.

As such you probably want to change the `AddData` method to accept 5 parameters (address, lastname, firstname, age and malefemale) and then to populate the columns with the respective data.

Additionally you then subsequently call `AddData` a number of times (4) for each data item (except malefemale). This will result in 4 rows being added per click of the add button. I believe that what you really want is for one row to be added as such you should only call `AddData` once with all 5 or 4 (perhaps you haven't got to malefemale as yet) data items. Thus you will end up with one row with all the respective data.

#### Edit after adding data was reported as working.

As you're having so many problems, many of which appear to be coming from pre-existing code. So it appears that much of the code is untested. I'd suggest a different approach. basically concentrate on getting something working and then add to this.

As such here's working code (pretty basic) that works and allows you to a) Add friends (bar gender as you'd probably want to select this) and b) list them via the view button.

First **AndroidManifest.xml** (**NOTE! only use this for comparison if needed**)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="mjt.so46145559friendsdb">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".friends">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".listdata"></activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**activity_friends.xml** The layout for the **friends** activity (very basic with no spinner) :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="mjt.so46145559friendsdb.friends">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/firstnameinput"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="firstname"
        android:inputType="text"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/lastnameinput"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="lastname"
        android:inputType="text"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ageinput"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLength="3"
        android:inputType="number"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/addressinput"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="address"
        android:inputType="text"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ADD"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/viewbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="VIEW"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Note! it might well be that you existing layout works.

**activity_listdata.xml** The layout for **listdata** activity invoked when the VIEW button is clicked (extremely basic).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/friendslist_heading"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/friendlist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**listdataitem.xml** the layout used for each item (row) displayed by the ListView in the **listdata** activity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstnamedisplay"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lastnamedisplay"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/agedisplay"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/addressdisplay"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

DatabaseHelper.java The SQLiteOpenHelper subclass, note some changes have been made (brownie points available for spotting them :))

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String TAG = "DatabaseHelper";

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "friends_table";
    public static final String IDCOL = "_id";
    public static final String COL1 = "firstname";
    public static final String COL2 = "lastname";
    public static final String COL3 = "malefemale";
    public static final String COL4 = "age";
    public static final String COL5 = "address";


    public DatabaseHelper (Context context) {
        super(context, TABLE_NAME, null, 1);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + IDCOL+ " TEXT PRIMARY KEY, " +
                COL1 + " TEXT, " +
                COL2 + " TEXT, " +
                COL3 + " TEXT, " +
                COL4 + " INTEGER, " +
                COL5 + " TEXT " +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(createTable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP IF TABLE EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean addData(String firstname, String lastname, String gender, int age, String address) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL1, firstname);
        contentValues.put(COL2, lastname);
        contentValues.put(COL3, gender);
        contentValues.put(COL4, age);
        contentValues.put(COL5, address);

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

        //if data as inserted inorrectly it will return -1
        if (result == 1)
            return false;
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns all data from DB
     */
    public Cursor getData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        return db.query(TABLE_NAME,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    }

    /**
     * Returns ID that matches the name
     * searches the DB and returns the ID associated with that name
     */
    public Cursor getItemID(String name) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT " + COL1 + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME +  // SELECT ID FROM DB
                " WHERE " + COL2 + " = '" + name + "'";             // WHERE THE LAST NAME = NAME SELECTED

        Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        return data;
    }

    /**
     * Alternative means of getting ID return it as a long rather in a cursor
     */
    public long getID(String firstname) {
        long rv = 0;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor csr = db.query(TABLE_NAME,null,COL2 + "=?",new String[]{firstname},null,null,null);
        if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
            rv = csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex(IDCOL));
        }
        csr.close();
        return rv;
    }

    /**
     * UPDATES THE NAME
     *
     * UPDATE TABLE > SET LASTNNAME(COL2) = newName = WHERE id = id in Question = AND LASTNAME(COL2) = oldName (was previously) >
     */
    public void updateName (String newName, int id, String oldName) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME + " SET " + COL2 +
                " = '" + newName + "' WHERE " + COL1 + " = '" + id + "'" +
                " AND " + COL2 + " = '" + oldName + "'";

        //LOGS THE NEW NAME
        Log.d(TAG, "updateName: query: " + query);
        Log.d(TAG, "updateName: Setting name to " + newName); // NEW NAME CHANGING IT TO
        db.execSQL(query); // EXECUTE QUERY
    }

    /**
     * DELETE FROM DATABASE
     * >>> DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE id = id passed AND name = name passed
     *
     */
    public void deleteName(int id, String name){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "
                + COL1 + " = '" + id + "'" +
                " AND " + COL2 + " = '" + name + "'";

        Log.d(TAG, "deleteName: query: " + query);
        Log.d(TAG, "deleteName: Deleting " + name + " from database.");
        db.execSQL(query); // EXECUTE QUERY
    }
}
```

**friends.java** (bare bones but it works, prettifying is up to you :))

```
public class friends extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText firstnameinput, lastnameinput, ageinput, addressinput;
    Button addbutton, viewbutton;
    DatabaseHelper dbhlpr;
    Context context;   //############### FIX_001

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_friends);
        context = this; //########## FIX_001

        firstnameinput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstnameinput);
        lastnameinput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lastnameinput);
        ageinput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ageinput);
        addressinput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addressinput);
        addbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addbutton);
        viewbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.viewbutton);

        dbhlpr = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        addbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                boolean addOK = true;
                int age_as_int = -1;

                String firstName = firstnameinput.getText().toString();
                String lastName = lastnameinput.getText().toString();
                String age = ageinput.getText().toString();
                String address = addressinput.getText().toString();

                if (firstName.length() < 1) {
                    toastMessage("You must enter something in this field!");
                    firstnameinput.requestFocus();
                    addOK = false;
                }
                if (lastName.length() < 1) {
                    toastMessage("You must enter something in this field!");
                    lastnameinput.requestFocus();
                    addOK = false;
                }
                if (age.length() < 1) {
                    toastMessage("You must enter something in this field!");
                    ageinput.requestFocus();
                    addOK = false;
                }
                if (address.length() < 1) {
                    toastMessage("You must enter something in this field!");
                    addressinput.requestFocus();
                    addOK = false;
                }
                try {
                    age_as_int = Integer.parseInt(age);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    toastMessage("You must enter a valid Number in this field!");
                    ageinput.requestFocus();
                    addOK = false;
                }

                if (addOK) {
                    dbhlpr.addData(firstName,lastName,"????",age_as_int,address);
                    toastMessage("Friend Added!");
                }

            }
        });
        viewbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context,listdata.class); //########## FIX_001
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    private void toastMessage(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(this,message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Finally a cheap and cheerful **listdata.java**

```
public class listdata extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView mListView;
    TextView firstname, lastname, age, address;
    DatabaseHelper dbhlpr;
    Cursor friendlist;
    SimpleCursorAdapter sca;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_listdata);

        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.friendlist);
        firstname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.firstnamedisplay);
        lastname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lastnamedisplay);
        age = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.agedisplay);
        address = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.addressdisplay);
        dbhlpr = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        friendlist = dbhlpr.getData();
        Log.d("CURSORCOUNT","Rows in Cursor is " + friendlist.getCount());

        // make a list of the columns from which the data is to be extracted
        String[] dbcolums = {
                DatabaseHelper.COL1,
                DatabaseHelper.COL2,
                DatabaseHelper.COL4,
                DatabaseHelper.COL5
        };

        // make a list of the view's id where the data is to be placed
        //Note each column will have a respective view
        int[] listviewids = {R.id.firstnamedisplay, R.id.lastnamedisplay, R.id.agedisplay, R.id.addressdisplay};

        // Setup the Adapter
        sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this,                           // The context
                R.layout.listdataitem,          // the lasyout for an item
                friendlist,                     // cursor with data
                dbcolums,                       // the list of DB columns to get data from
                listviewids,                    // the views in the layout where to place the data
                0                               // don't worry
        );

        // Finally tie the adapter to the ListView
        mListView.setAdapter(sca);
    }
}
```

take these, perhaps even start a new project, **AS THEY ARE**, get it working and then add small bits at a time. Create new questions when you have problems. Please do not amend questions removing stuff that you've added basically only add to a question asked. (very confusing with bits going). Also always make it very clear what has been added.

It works as per :-

a) When first started :-

[image]

b) Adding data :-

[image]

c) View :-

[image]

Comment: Right! So the data seems now to successfully add (or so it seems) as there is no error in the logcat when clicking "ADD" when adding data. However, when i click on the "VIEW DATA" button to show the entries, the error seems to be in the above logcat...

Comment: Does the log include the output from `Log.d("CURSORCOUNT", "Number of rows in Cursor =");`? I suspect that it does. If so what is the count?

Comment: thanks for taking the time to re modify the code :) Seems to be taking a lot longer than expected but I'm sure I'll get there eventually! So ran your code, seem to be working perfectly. I have amended the `friends.java` file above to match yours.  When I try to **"VIEW DATA"** the program stops. I believe it has something to do with the         `viewbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) { ... } ` section in **friends.java**. I have also updated the error in the **logcat** above.

Comment: @ccodes It appears that the **context** for the intent is null. I think this is because you have inadvertently missed/deleted the code that sets the context (**`context = this;`**) that follows the line **`setContentView(R.layout.activity_friends);`**. (I removed `context = this;` and this causes the failure).

Comment: @ccodes PS The above is all in **friends.java**. I've marked the relevant lines of code with **`//############### FIX_001`** check that what you have coded matches all three such lines in the code above. PPS put it up on GitHub as https://github.com/Mike-j-t/SO46145559FriendsDB from Android Studio with version control.

Comment: thanks! Nevermind I got my original code working :) I've got it sucessfully save the data to the listview and can now click on it to take me to the edit/save/delete screen (:D). If you're interested, I now have a new problem (newbie life) if you like, feel free to have a look =D. [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46190496/android-studio-novice-edit-save-delete-record-from-listview)

Comment: @ccodes already seen it. However suggest you have a look at the github above it's as you can use github from within Android Studio including version control. So you can revert changes etc it also keeps all individual files seperate. Much better than just dumping file containing all code. Plenty of guides on how to get it working from studio.